# i want to create a procedure with a view of a select in toad oracle

Tags: oracle, select, stored-procedures, view

I want to create a procedure with a view of a select in toad oracle to introduce three parameters and make a select

```
create or replace procedure busqueda (nomlu varchar ,ape varchar,apese varchar) 
as
begin
execute immediate  'create view vprueba as
    select
        alu.t_nombre, 
        alu.t_apellido1, 
        alu.t_apellido2,
    from 
        tlalumnos alu
    where 
        t_nombre = nomlu
        and t_apellido1 =ape 
        and t_apellido2 =apese;

end busqueda;
```

Comment: You lost me after replace

Comment: Creating a view for a specific persons name is not likely to be the correct solution. Regarding the code; you are missing a single quote after the word 'apese' in your select.

Comment: ... and there's a dangling `,` after `alu.t_apellido2` in your select.

Comment: There is no question in your post, we need to guess what you want.
What is the problem are you facing? What is the error message you get when compiling? The more info you give, the best we can help.
Also, unless you have some other code dropping the view, that procedure will run successfully only once. The second time you run it you will face a `ORA-00955 name is already used by an existing object` error. If you want to overwrite the view, you can use `create or replace view`. But I agree with @BriteSponge, this doesn't look like the right design.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the closing quote on the `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` string, and you'll have to convert the parameters to strings and concatenate the values into the `CREATE VIEW`:

```
create or replace procedure busqueda (nomlu varchar ,ape varchar,apese varchar) 
as
begin
execute immediate  'create OR REPLACE view vprueba as
    select
        alu.t_nombre, 
        alu.t_apellido1, 
        alu.t_apellido2,
    from 
        tlalumnos alu
    where 
        t_nombre = ''' || TO_CHAR(nomlu) || '''' ||
      ' and t_apellido1 = ''' || TO_CHAR(ape) || '''' ||
      ' and t_apellido2 = ''' || TO_CHAR(apese) || '''';
end busqueda;
```

Try working with that and see if it gets you closer to a solution.